# Win7 C++ - kiosk mode application does not have admin access

Tags: permissions, registry, qt5, kiosk

I'm working on a Kiosk system and I need to be able to lock down the keyboard and turn off the logon screen options on the fly.  So at startup my code does these things, and if a security dongle is inserted, it undoes them.

Works fine in non-Kiosk, when I right-click the application and select "Run as administrator".  The keyboard is locked down (I'm trapping key strokes), but the logon screen continues to come up with all five option buttons.  I added debug writes to a file and found that the reason was "access denied".

My Kiosk is set up with a user that has been given administrator rights, and the application pathname (C:\\.exe) has been set as the Shell value in HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon.  Since this application will run as session 0, I am not sure what else needs to be done to give it the rights to disable and enable the five logon screen options.

Answer (score 2):

I have experience in develop Kiosk application and I advise you next solution. this is universal solution and works as expected. Run application in logon session - is bad idea. Run app Via winlogon regkey wil not run in session0, it will run app in user session.

Windows kiosk mode need next steps:

- Create user for kiosk mode
- Set next registry key for this user as path to your application:

Windows XP/7:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon]
"Shell"="C:\\full\\path\\to\\your\\application.exe>"
```

Windows 8 and later:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System]
"Shell"="C:\\full\\path\\to\\your\\application.exe>"
```

Autologin for kiosk user:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon] 
"AutoAdminLogon"="1"
"ForceAutoLogon"="1"
"DefaultUserName"="kiosk"
"DefaultDomainName"="<place here pc hostname>"
"DefaultPassword"=""
```

*[Option]* If you need to disable Ctrl+Alt+Del, then use this registry key value ("") or you can place there own application:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Image File Execution Options\taskmgr.exe]
"Debugger"="\"\""
```

Create kiosk user with this your application as shell and create/activate admin with password. With autologin to load as admin press shift when windows loading and before autologin or while logging out - windows will not autologin and show users list. Or, you can not set autologin and windows will show 2 users: admin and kiosk user with this your software.

To disable user input use WINAPI [BlockInput](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646290(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
BOOL WINAPI BlockInput(
  _In_ BOOL fBlockIt
);
```

It can be enabled by ctrl+alt+del - in this case with solution above your programm can disable it again.

Comment: Tried to follow your steps but didn't work for me... Created a "Kiosk" user, then logged in it, and as Administrator I added the Registry key Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System, then in it added a value "Shell" pointing to a program .exe. But after signing out and in into Kiosk, the program doesn't launch. Just the explorer.exe. Any advice please?

Comment: Did you rebooted PC?

Comment: Don't remember. Tried other manips since then... But, why, the Registry is updated only at (re)boot?

Comment: Old legacy code. Usually windows loads registry to memory only once after PC boot. Anyway, this solution is real working solution, and I used it in production. If something not working — check again all steps/options. What is your OS version?

Comment: Ah okay. Finally you are right, my other manips (on a Win10) essentially boils down to beginning of your post. Problem was, I was launching regedit as the Administrator, so the HKCU was referrring to it. Temporarly added rights to the Kiosk user, and modified registry - it works! Thanks. PS Registry seems to be updated even without reboot, or at least with only log off.